# Recycle ImageViews to avoid OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, imageview, out-of-memory, android-imageview

In some phones (especially Samsungs), the application gives an error of OutOfMemory.

I use a ViewFlipper with 4 ImageViews which they are shown in a tutorial.

I have found no way to remedy the error or recycle imageviews.

This is the method that manages the ViewFlipper:

```
private void changeBackground(int position) {

    switch (position) {

        case 1:
            mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_onboarding);
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_inverse_onboarding);
            break;

        case 2:
            mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_onboarding);
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_inverse_onboarding);
            break;

        case 3:
            mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(3);
            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_onboarding);
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_inverse_onboarding);
            break;

        default:
            mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_onboarding);
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_clockwise_inverse_onboarding);
            break;

    }

}
```

The method is called each time you change pages in a ViewPager.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       changeBackground(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
}
```

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the images you are using. If you are only using 4 images, they are likely gigantic, and can be sampled down.

Comment: The Images take up 65kb and 750x1330

Comment: The images might be 65kb on disk, but once they have been decoded it could be significantly more. What happens if you sample those images down to say, 75x133 for testing purposes?

Comment: @Knossos I solve mi problem loading the images with Glide! I also try your option for future use. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to use Image loader library for loading images.
You can use :

1. Universal Image loader
2. Picasso
3. Glide

This library uses for bitmap memory management and after using this library you didn't face OutOfMemoryError exeption.

Comment: I normally use Glide, but in this case must be preloaded as I had not thought of that. I am going to try :)

Comment: try Universal Image loader and check it.

Comment: With Glide works perfect! Thanks for opening my eyes! :D